# if Column 1 and column 2 are equal in a dataset then i have to print the corresponding column2 values using R programming

Tags: r

if Column 1 and column 2 are equal in a dataset then i have to print the corresponding column2 values using R

```
col1 <- c("sea","very","geo","low")
col2 <- c("sea","make","geo","low")
```

i need output as

```
[1] sea
[2] geo
```

Comment: The question is not clear.  May be try `intersect(col1, col2)` or `col1[col1 == col2]`

Comment: What do you mean equal? In length? In elements?

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed you want this in something like a dataframe with a third column, and are looking for the strings to match.

```
example_df <- data_frame(col1, col2)
example_df$col3 <- ifelse (col1 == col2, col2, NA)
```

You can also simply get the output printed.

```
for (i in 1:length(col1)) {
if (col1[i] == col2[i]) {print(col2[i])}
}
```

(Both of these match "low", which as far as I can tell is the same in both col1 and col2...)